# If someone down-votes an answer, and gives a reason that the answer-er agrees with, should the answer-er delete the answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

The situation was that someone asked a lazy question and I gave a lazy answer and got down-voted. The down-voter was kind enough to comment with a reason. I deleted my answer but wanted to know if this is what is expected / appreciated by the community.

Comment: A further option is to edit the answer so that the reason for the downvote is no longer given.

Answer (score 13):

It's up to you whether you want to delete your answer or not. You can either leave it around and it may continue accumulating downvotes, or delete it if you think it isn't worth keeping around.

If an answer is harmful or otherwise egregiously bad enough the community may vote to delete it, but that doesn't usually happen.